# Webstorm: Can't run simple nestjs app. Error: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, nestjs, webstorm

I created a default nestjs project using

```
nest new my-nestjs-01
```

command from [this](https://codingthesmartway.com/nestjs-for-absolute-beginners/) tutorial. I configured Webstorm to run typescript files like this:

[image]

So now when I open a `.ts` file in editor and click

[image]

at the top, the current opened file gets executed.

However when I execute **main.ts** I get this error:

```
 Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

This is the default project code that has been generated for me with the above `nest` command. I tried adding additional options to `tsconfig.json` to fix the error, but it didn't help:

**tsconfig.json**:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "js/ts.implicitProjectConfig.experimentalDecorators":true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true

  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/app.service.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

**main.ts**:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

**app.module.ts**:

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {} // <-- error here
```

How do I fix it? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Solution from suggested [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172130/4759176):

```
Pasting my configuration from tsconfig.json into the tsconfig.spec.json file fixed the issue.
```

**did not** solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [61171354](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171354/jetbrains-webstorm-gives-warning-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-featu) or [40728785](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728785/webstorm-2016-3-error-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-feature-that-is)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetbrains WebStorm gives warning: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171354/jetbrains-webstorm-gives-warning-experimental-support-for-decorators-is-a-featu)

Comment: @Shivam I created the `tsconfig.spec.json` and put the contents of `tsconfig.json` in it. Running `main.ts` still gives the same error

Comment: Does running `node -r ts-node/register src/main.ts` in shell work?

Comment: @parsecer I tried the same as you did and it worked for me in WebStorm, though I use windows.  Try to specify your working directory in the run configuration fully without the `~`, and if it doesn't work, make sure that your WebStorm is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

My catch with WebStorm x NestJs RUN CONFIGURATION, was simply that I was not point to the correct JavaScript file (needs to point to the main.js file transcripted).
For the default installation of NestJs, this main.js file is located in the **~/dist folder;** In my case, image below shows a working config:
[image]